# How to install Codepro plugin in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Now I am using Eclipse Kepler Version: 3.9.1.201308190730, but i don't how to configure "CodePro AnalytiX" plugin in Eclipse Kepler. Is it possible to configure "CodePro AnalytiX"  in my current Eclipse Kepler?
And is "CodePro AnalytiX" plugin the correct tool for testing code perfomance? Otherwise suggest any other tool for code testing.

Answer (score 4):

-Open Eclipse Kepler
-Help -> install new software
-enter this URL:
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.6
-Enter

- If you found any other good tool for persistance tests, please let me know :)

Enjoy!

Comment: It is compatible with Eclipse Luna?

Comment: Installed 3.7 on Luna and it seems to run just fine.  It does give a warning "At least one Google product installed into this version of Eclipse was compiled and built for a different version of Eclipse".

Answer (score 1):

All the url's specified in this page are no longer valid.

Eclipse version Installation instructions

Direct plugin link
Eclipse 4.6 (Neon)  Plugin for Eclipse 4.6 (Neon)   https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.6
Eclipse 4.5 (Mars)  Plugin for Eclipse 4.5 (Mars)   https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.5
Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)  Plugin for Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)   https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4
If you are looking for older versions of the plugin, click here.

If you are having trouble installing from the update sites (due to firewall issues, for instance), you can install the Google Plugin for Eclipse by downloading and installing an archive of the update site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its compatible for eclipse version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: Where did you find it?